# Set the topViewController before loading ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I am following [this](http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/slide-out-navigation/) tutorial to make a Sliding app.

I have added the [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController) in my project.

I have performed only few steps from the tutorial then I have encountered the error.

I have written nothing in code except the code from tutorial i.e.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ToDoView"];
}
```

When I run the app my app crashes and showing me this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Missing topViewController', 
reason: 'Set the topViewController before loading ECSlidingViewController'
```

I searched google and Tried many ways some of them are form the links:

[First Link](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/wiki/Storyboards-Guide)

[Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081513/ecslidingviewcontroller-not-first-view)

I am not able to find any genuine solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's Strange when i Interchange the lines in ViewDidLoad it works file:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{

  self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ToDoView"];

   [super viewDidLoad];

 }
```